# Command working in bash but not in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

Here is my Makefile that is used to compile my C++ project:

```
src := $(shell find src/ -name *.cpp)
obj := $(patsubst src/*.cpp, build/%.o, $(server_source_files))

server: objects
    g++ $(obj) -o server

objects: src
    mkdir -p build/ && \
    cd build/ && \
    g++ -O2 -c $(find ../src/ -name *.cpp) && \
    cd ..

clean:
    rm -r build/
    rm server
```

The problem is, the Makefile fails at the line `g++ -O2 -c $(find ../src/ -name *.cpp) && \`, which is executed from inside of the `build/` directory. This command works, when I run it in bash, but doesn't work here. Why? I'm new to writing Makefiles.

I think it's also worth mentioning, that if I put `shell` before the `find ../src/ -name *.cpp`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Because Make tries to interpret it as a Make function. Use either `$(shell find` or `$$(find`.

Comment: If you want the shell to see a `$` you have to escape it from make, otherwise make will assume it's a make variable reference.  Write `$$(find ../src/ ...` instead

Comment: In general it's a code smell to use make's `$(shell ...` function in a recipe.  At least IMO.  It can cause unnecessary issues.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried `$(shell find` but it didn't work, however, `$$(find` worked. Now I have another error regarding the `g++ $(obj) -o server` line (no input files). It looks like the obj variable is somehow wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it. I had forgot to rename the variable on line 2.

Comment: To clarify, it was the `$(server_source_files)` that was causing the error, because I had previously renamed the `src` and `obj` variables, but forgot to rename that one.